# GSA indexed pages showing up in result sets with the title set to "Unable to convert file."

Tags: google-search-appliance

GSA indexed pages showing up in result sets with the title set to "Unable to convert file." File is crawled successfully w/o any error. Please help me identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Google fixed the following bug in GSA software-version 7.4.0.G.114:

> 8461531: Content truncated at 32MB if web server does not send Content-Length
>   header and fails conversion in case of binary file types such as PDF
>   or Office.

So, binary files larger than 32MB don't get properly indexed in previous versions. You could try challenging this with Google Support and see if your GSA is affected by this bug. Or you could perform the upgrade to the latest version (which is 7.4.0.G.120).